# Track On then Delete Selection then Track Off

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can anyone provide a Microsoft Word VBA or macro that does this. I want to make a selection of simple text, then I want to run a macro the does this:

**Track Changes - On >> Delete Selection >> Track Changes - Off**

This following macro does not work because lines 1 and 3 simply toggles the Track Changes from its current status. Therefore, if TC is currently ON, the macro begins by switching TC to OFF (bad result).

```
  ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
  Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Document.TrackRevisions` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/document-trackrevisions-property-word) is a Boolean, so you can simply write:

```
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
```

Note that you may want instead to put the TR back to its original state:

```
Dim tr As Boolean
tr = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions

ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = tr
```